# Best practices : Symfony comments

Tags: symfony, interface, architecture

In my application, I have to allow my users to comments two kind of entities : Recipe and News.

I want to know what is the best practice for doing it. 
A Comment object with a ref_id(integer) and ref(string) that I manage manually or a commun interface between my to entity and something like @ManyToMany(targetEntoty="MyInterfaceHere") in my Comment object ?

Thanks you for your answers

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I didn't understand your aim.

Comment: I want to be able to comment both my recipes and my news. I know how to do this by creating two field (ref_id and ref) in my Comment class. But I think it's a little durty.. I want to know if there is a better solution for that (like an interface or something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well a good implementation would be if Recipes and News extend an abstract class

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappedSuperclass;

/**
 * Abstract base class
 *
 * @MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class EntityWithComments {
   /**
   *
   *@ORM(many-to-bla)
   */
   private $comments;
   public function addComment(){...};
   public function removeComment(){...};
   public function getComments(){...};
   ...
```

and your classes extend it, for example Recipe:

```
class Recipe extends EntityWithComments { ...
```

so this way you can

```
$recipe->addComment($comment);
$news->addComment($comment);
```

straightforward ...